# How do I add url to a lightbox in Webflow?

Tags: javascript, web, webflow

I'm working on a Webflow site. On the home page we have a lightbox with a video. The user must click a button to view the lightbox. We would like the URL to change when the lightbox is visible to make the video in the lightbox more shareable.

How can I make a URL for a lightbox?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Webflow has decent JavaScript capabilities, this is one strategy:

1. The method that actually changes what's in the browser URL box and history without reloading the page is [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState). Linked is the MDN documentation explaining how to use it.
2. To get the URL for the page, you can use [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)
3. The part of the URL you will likely be changing is the URL query parameters. If it's just one time, you can probably just do this manually, e.g. add /?lightbox=true to the end of the base URL. JS has a handy interface called [URLSearchParams()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) that you can use to define those parameters and print them into a string.
4. When the page loads, you'll need a function the check whether the URL includes the parameter for the lightbox, and what its value is. You can do that with URlSearchParams(). Example:

   var urlS=new URLSearchParams(window.location.search); //this gets whatever is in the url parameters when the page loads 
   var lightbox=urlS.get('lightbox'); //this gets the lightbox parameter

   if(lightbox==true){
   lightboxActivate();
   }